# How do I expose local IIS to other PCs on Windows 7?

Tags: iis-7, windows-7

I found the good article to do that http://msdnbangladesh.net/blogs/munnacs/archive/2009/06/13/exposing-your-local-iis-to-network-in-windows-xp.aspx ,but it's for Windows XP and I'm using Windows 7 which gets extremely complicated Firewall settings.

So here is my question, how can I achieve the same thing on Windows 7 as the article does on XP?

Thanks in advance, 
yokyo

Edit
Sorry, I fixed the link :p

Comment: Your link to the article is invalid. PJMSERV is a local network name, not an internet web server name.

Comment: This question probably belongs on superuser.com, rather than stackoverflow.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can achieve the same thing in Windows 7 by doing the following:

1. Start -> Control Panel
2. System and Security
3. Under the Windows Firewall heading:

   - Allow a program through the Windows Firewall
4. Check the HTTP and HTTPS protocols in the list:

   - Secure World Wide Web Services (HTTPS)
   - Web Management Service (HTTP)
   - Word Wide Web Services (HTTP)

Comment: Thanks a lot jrista! Okay, next time I'll post this kind of questions to the superuser.com.

Answer (score 2):

Using Windows 10 and I wasn't able to get it to work with this version. Secure World Wide Web Services (HTTPS) and Web Management Service (HTTP) aren't on the list and just World Wide Web Services didn't help.

What eventually worked was setting up an inbound rule for the specific ports my IIS site was using [these instructions](https://superuser.com/a/144543/524501)