# Can we make IIS Localhost URL accessible by others?

Tags: iis, web-deployment, iis-8

I have published my website in IIS. The url is http://localhost/MyDemo. I want to give this url for testing to other people (anyone). How can I do that?

I tried to give sharing permission to "Everyone" in the Edit Permission.

Please help.

Comment: Well, just replace `localhost` with the name of your computer (and configure your firewall, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244158/how-do-i-expose-local-iis-to-other-pcs-on-windows-7). If you want to grant access via the internet, you probably need to forward port 80, which depends on you router (search for "Port Forwarding").

Comment: https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html Run Binding Diagnostics to learn how each binding would be accessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are standard port forwarding tools that allow you to do this. 
A helpful link here - https://www.sitepoint.com/accessing-localhost-from-anywhere/

Now ngRok is a tool I have used many a times. Its usage is pretty straightforward.

It can be downloaded from here - https://ngrok.com/download

Once ngRok is downloaded, you have to open the ngrok.exe, and it opens a console window.

[image]

Execute the following command

```
ngrok http 4983 -host-header="localhost:4983"
```

Here 4983 is a port number, in case you have one.

Once the command is executed the tool opens up a Url, which is accessible from anywhere. The below image is your Url, and it will be valid for a certain duration of time (if you are using the tool for free).

[image]